# Why part of this mesh disappears after adding booleans?

Tags: mesh, mirror, boolean-modifier

I recently started learning blender and after few youtube tutorials I wanted to do something by myself. I added a cube, divided it in half, added mirror modifier, cut some shapes with a knife, added some cutters and added boolean modifiers. I also added a small cylinder in edit mode.
[image]

I realized that when I turn on any of these booleans, cylinder disappears.
[image]

I also realized that when booleans are on and I turn off mirror modifier, cylinder appears and one cutter becomes a mesh.
[image]

And when i shade it auto smooth it gets absolutely destroyed so I assume I've done everything as bad as possible.
[image]

How can I fix all of that?

[image]

Comment: I don't know why the *Exact* option make your *Boolean* modifiers fail but if you choose *Fast* instead they will work. As for the shading, right click on the object and *Shade Smooth*, then go into the *Data* panel and under *Geometry Data* click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* and under *Normals* activate *Auto Smooth*. Also make sure that the cutter objects are smooth as well.

Comment: Thanks! Now everything works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the *Exact* option make your *Boolean* modifiers fail but you can activate the *Solver Options > Self Intersection* option or choose *Fast* instead of *Exact* and it will work.

As for the shading, right click on the object and *Shade Smooth*, then go into the *Data* panel and under *Geometry Data* click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* and under *Normals* activate *Auto Smooth*. Also make sure that the cutter objects are smooth as well.